# Python 3.4 won't use information from .json file

Tags: python, json

I am currently working on a small Python clock. The clock doesn't have anything to do with real time, it was just for a fun side project. After every second, the clock is supposed to save the hour, minute, second, time of day, and other information. It saves the information, but when I restart the program, it doesn't reuse the information. Here is my code:

```
#Importations
import jsonpickle
import os
import sys
import time
#Setups
SAVEGAME_FILENAME = 'time.json'
game_state = dict()
#Class
class clocktime(object):
    def __init__(self, hour, minute, second, timeday, day):
        self.hour = hour
        self.minute = minute
        self.second = second
        self.timeday = timeday
        self.day = day  
#Load Program Save
def load_game():
    """This runs if a .json file IS found"""
    with open(SAVEGAME_FILENAME, 'r') as savegame:
        state = jsonpickle.decode(savegame.read())
    return state
#Save Program to JSON
def save_game():
    """This saves the program to a .json file."""
    global game_state
    with open(SAVEGAME_FILENAME, 'w') as savegame:
        savegame.write(jsonpickle.encode(game_state))
#Initialize Program
def initialize_game():
    """Runs if no AISave is found"""
    hour = 1
    minute = 0
    second = 0
    timeday = 1
    day = ('am')
    the_time = clocktime(hour, minute, second, timeday, day)

    state = dict()
    state['the_time'] = [the_time]
    return state
#Clear Screen
def cls():
    os.system('cls')
#Clock Program
def clock():
    hour = 1
    minute = 0
    second = 0
    timeday = 1
    day = ('am')
    global game_state
    while True:
        print ("The time is: %s" % hour + ":%s" % minute + ":%s" % second + " %s" % day)
        print ("             H M S")
        print ("H = Hour, M = Minute, S = Second")   
        time.sleep(0.5)
        cls()
        second += 1
        save_game()
        if second == 60:
            minute += 1
            second = 0
        if minute == 60:
            hour += 1
            minute = 0
        if hour == 13:
            hour = 1
            timeday += 1
        if timeday == 1:
            day = ('am')
        if timeday == 2:
            day = ('pm')
        if timeday == 3:
            day = 0
        game_state['the_time'][0].hour = hour
        game_state['the_time'][0].minute = minute
        game_state['the_time'][0].second = second
        game_state['the_time'][0].timeday = timeday 
#Main Program
def main():
    """Main function. Check if a savegame exists, and if so, load it. Otherwise
    initialize the game state with defaults. Finally, start the game."""
    global game_state

    if not os.path.isfile(SAVEGAME_FILENAME):
        game_state = initialize_game()
    else:
        game_state = load_game()
    clock()
#Launch Code
if __name__ == "__main__":
    isSaveOn = False
    main()
```

Comment: My first hunch would be that it cannot find the `SAVEGAME` file. Either the `SAVEGAME_FILENAME` constant points to an incorrect path or there is a permission issue. Seeing the code, when (for whatever reason) the file cannot be loaded, it invokes the `initialize_game()` function to setup it's state.

Comment: It ignores the saved values because the beginning of `clock()` always initializes the local time values it uses with hardcoded defaults instead copying whatever values are currently in `game_state['the_time']` to allow it can pick-up where it left off.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting `game_state` with initial `hour`/`minute`/`second`/`timeday` values ) at the end of the loop when you save them, and they are always `1`/`0`/`0`/`1` regardless of the `game_state`. So basically you load `game_state` and then overwrite it with default values. Replace initializations in `clock` function to something like this:

```
# ...
def clock():
    # Change to this:
    hour = game_state['the_time'][0].hour
    minute = game_state['the_time'][0].minute
    second = game_state['the_time'][0].second
    timeday = game_state['the_time'][0].timeday

    while True:
        # (displaying time and incrementing values)

        game_state['the_time'][0].hour = hour
        game_state['the_time'][0].minute = minute
        game_state['the_time'][0].second = second
        game_state['the_time'][0].timeday = timeday

        # Move save_game here (to the end of loop):
        save_game()
```